# Benchmarking under SELinux Sandbox with Phoronix Test Suite

Tags: performance, selinux, benchmark, profiling, sandbox

I would like to run the Phoronix Test Suite 6.2.2 under the SELinux sandbox on Fedora 23, but I can't execute it using `$ sandbox ./phoronix-test-suite`. I probably don't have the correct SELinux type. I would like to run the following test suites under the sandbox.

- Disk Test Suite
- Desktop Graphics
- Memory Test Suite
- Networking Test Suite
- Kernel
- Video Encoding
- Linux System
- Cryptography
- CPU / Processor Suite

Here is what I have tried so far.

```
[slazer@localhost phoronix-test-suite]$ seinfo -t | egrep '^   sandbox'
   sandbox_x_client_t
   sandbox_net_client_t
   sandbox_xserver_tmpfs_t
   sandbox_web_client_tmpfs_t
   sandbox_devpts_t
   sandbox_xserver_t
   sandbox_exec_t
   sandbox_file_t
   sandbox_xserver_input_xevent_t
   sandbox_x_t
   sandbox_web_client_t
   sandbox_min_t
   sandbox_net_t
   sandbox_web_t
   sandbox_min_client_t
   sandbox_net_client_tmpfs_t
   sandbox_x_client_tmpfs_t
   sandbox_xserver_xproperty_t
   sandbox_t
   sandbox_min_client_tmpfs_t

[slazer@localhost phoronix-test-suite]$ pwd
/home/slazer/Downloads/phoronix-test-suite

[slazer@localhost phoronix-test-suite]$ ls
AUTHORS  ChangeLog  COPYING  deploy  documentation  install-sh  phoronix-test-suite  phoronix-test-suite.bat  pts-core  README.md  sehome  tmp

[slazer@localhost phoronix-test-suite]$ sandbox ./phoronix-test-suite
/bin/sh: ./phoronix-test-suite: Permission denied

[slazer@localhost phoronix-test-suite]$ sandbox -M -H sehome/ -T tmp/ -t sandbox_exec_t -X ./phoronix-test-suite
/usr/bin/sandbox:437: PyGIWarning: Gtk was imported without specifying a version first. Use gi.require_version('Gtk', '3.0') before import to ensure that the right version gets loaded.
  from gi.repository import Gtk
Could not set exec context to unconfined_u:unconfined_r:sandbox_exec_t:s0:c460,c525. Invalid argument

[slazer@localhost phoronix-test-suite]$ sandbox -M -H sehome/ -T tmp/ -t sandbox_exec_t ./phoronix-test-suite
Could not set exec context to unconfined_u:unconfined_r:sandbox_exec_t:s0:c106,c534. Invalid argument

[slazer@localhost phoronix-test-suite]$ sandbox -M -H sehome/ -T tmp/ -t sandbox_x_t -X ./phoronix-test-suite
/usr/bin/sandbox:437: PyGIWarning: Gtk was imported without specifying a version first. Use gi.require_version('Gtk', '3.0') before import to ensure that the right version gets loaded.
  from gi.repository import Gtk
Couldn't exec /home/slazer/Downloads/phoronix-test-suite/phoronix-test-suite: Permission denied
XIO:  fatal IO error 11 (Resource temporarily unavailable) on X server ":1"
      after 1700 requests (1700 known processed) with 0 events remaining.

[slazer@localhost phoronix-test-suite]$ sandbox -M -H sehome/ -T tmp/ -t sandbox_t ./phoronix-test-suite
Failed to execute command /home/slazer/Downloads/phoronix-test-suite/phoronix-test-suite: Permission denied

[slazer@localhost phoronix-test-suite]$ sandbox -M -H sehome/ -T tmp/ -t sandbox_file_t ./phoronix-test-suite
Failed to execute command /home/slazer/Downloads/phoronix-test-suite/phoronix-test-suite: Operation not permitted

[slazer@localhost phoronix-test-suite]$ sandbox -M -H sehome/ -T tmp/ -t sandbox_net_t ./phoronix-test-suite
Failed to execute command /home/slazer/Downloads/phoronix-test-suite/phoronix-test-suite: Permission denied
```

Comment: what are you trying to achieve by running that under SELinux `sandbox`?

Comment: @Jakuje I am measuring the performance degradation of running an application in a SELinux Sandbox, in comparison with running it natively.

Comment: I am afraid that under this sandbox, some of the required tasks will not work. You might try to run it under `strace` to check why exactly is it failing. If it is X application, you should certainly use `-X` switch. But I don't have fedora around here.